# Encoding to Decoding

Tags: c#, .net-core, encoding, ascii, decode

I am returning a list of records and setting those records as

```
_cache.Set(key, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result.ToString()), new DistributedCacheEntryOptions {Sliding Expiration = new TimeSpan(0,0,24)})
```

So on setting I'm getting encoded values, how can I get decoded records?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()`?

Answer (score 0):

You would decode the bytes when you pull them from cache.

```
var bytes = _cache.Get<byte[]>(key);
results = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```